# What does "noise power is assumed to be the same at all nodes

Tags: noise

I was reading a paper about communications between nodes, and in the simulation section they gave the condition of the simulation as follow :

"...The noise power is assumed to be the same at all nodes..."

In the simulation it is never stated that the transmit power of all nodes are not the same, but if you put them so that they are equal you get an error. My guess is that they mean the noise variances $σ^2$ of the nodes are the same. However the simulation result is way off the mark from the result in the paper.

Did I understand their meaning properly?

Comment: Yes, it means the noise variance is the same. Can you give more details about the simulations in the paper and how you approached it?

Comment: @BlackMath The simulations is from "DEVICE-TO-DEVICE COMMUNICATIONS:
THE PHYSICAL LAYER SECURITY ADVANTAGE" about measuring secrecy outage probability (SOP) between two modes, one is through a relay R and the other directly between two users A and B, with the present of eavesdropper E.

Comment: The paper derived two formula to calculate the SOPs, based on the location of the eavesdropper. The model based on the fact that SNR is propotional to distance power path loss exponent, and disproportional to noise variance.They assumed that the distances between A, B, and R, and between E and R is known; all SNR between A, B, R is equal, known path loss exponent, target secret rate = 1, number of antennas from R and E is known. Then they find the SOPs as a function of SNR and the SOPs as a function of number of antenna R have.

Comment: I followed the mathematical formula, assuming the transmit power P is given. With known path loss, known distance, I calculate the noise variance value based on given average SNR pAB , which is shared between all nodes, thus find out the according average SNR pAE and pRE. This allow me to map out a very complicated formula f(pAE,pRE,pAB,NR) (NR is the number of antenna R have).

In the paper they always have unity SOP values except when E is in an extreme location. In my simulation they have a weird curve, that SOP is prone to attack when SNR level close to 0 but drop in every other SNR.

Comment: I was thinking of sharing the formulas, and how you simulated them in a code, instead of explaining the system model.

Comment: Why do you need to evaluate the noise variance from the SNR? The same noise variance implies the same average SNR for all nodes if the channels are i.i.d.

Comment: @BlackMath thank you, it turned out that the noise variance from the SNR is actually assumed to be the same for all nodes. What messed up the simulation is the calculation for average SNR in the relay.

About the formula, it is hideously long and need background explanation which is done very good in the paper. If you want I will type it out, but expect to be amazed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although noise is often called *channel noise* in various block diagrams of radio-frequency (RF) communications systems that communications analysts draw, the truth of the matter is that most *actual RF channels* are mostly noiseless, and what is referred to as the channel noise is primarily *thermal noise* in the resistive elements in the front end of the *receiver*.  The noise power in the receiver that communications engineers have to contend with is thus determined by the temperature of those resistors (and the value of those resistors).  Thus, assuming that the receivers in the various "nodes" are identical and also in the same geographical area so that all the receivers can be expected to be at the same temperature, it is reasonable to use a model in which the noise power is the same in all of the receivers.

Comment: The strange thing is that throughout the paper and the analytical formula they never mentioned noise power at all. The only thing about noise they included is noise variance. In the model building they stated that the two nodes they want to observe had "spatial white noise with variance x and y".

Comment: @Kodiak They obviously mean that they have already translated _continuous-time_ RF signals into _discrete-time_ baseband equivalents and so the noise power means the same as the noise variance.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!